# Book Identification: Robot Pterodactyl on cover

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a book I found in middle school library around 1993 or 94. Do not know if it was a recent release.

It was a sci fi book with a teen or early adult female POV character.

POV character references an older brother or relative that is away on a job or mission at the start of book.

The cover is a simple landscape of green plains with blue sky background. Possibly a domed city and/or vehicles on the plain.

The key element I remember from the cover is a metallic pterodactyl that seemed to be a robot or ornithopter.

Possibly by Piers Anthony or would have been nearby Piers Anthony books.

Comment: You've told us almost nothing about the plot here, which makes this extremely difficult to search for. Can you remember anything about what actually happened in the story? Do you remember any specific scenes, or lines of dialogue, or any other characters? What kind of time period or world was the story set in? And were there any actual dinosaurs (you mentioned a possible robot/metallic pterodactyl)? If you have anything at all to add to your description, please [edit] it into your question.